# how to import with custom path in nx jest?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, nomachine-nx

Im trying to create unit testing with jest & expo.
Before, I was use a custom path for import the component with configurations like this

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["src/app/assets/*"],
      "@icons/*": ["src/app/assets/svg/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/app/components/*"],
      "@features/*": ["src/app/features/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/app/utils/*"],
      "@store/*": ["src/app/store/*"],
      "@navigations/*": ["src/app/navigations/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["src/app/hooks/*"],
      "@screens/*": ["src/app/screens/*"],
      "@libs/*": ["src/app/libs/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to use moduleNameMapper but I still got the same error

and this is my jest.config.ts

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'playtopia-app',
  resolver: '@nx/jest/plugins/resolver',
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html', 'tsx', 'jsx'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test-setup.ts', '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.svg$': '@nx/expo/plugins/jest/svg-mock',
    '@assets': '<rootDir>/app/assets',
  },
};
```

[image]

Does anyone have experience in solving this?

Thank you